# fscanf in a loop saving to the same array causes spaces to fill array

Tags: c, scanf

I have a file formatted like:

```
01,Name1
02,Name2
03,Name3
04,Name4
05,Name5
```

I am tying it make it so that a user can type in a number like 01, or 02 and the corresponding name will be returned. This works fine when I type 01. However when I type any number after it doesn't work and it seems like when I replace the loop with:

```
fscanf(fp,"%20[^,],%s[^\n]",ln,name);
printf("1=%c 2=%c 3=%c 4=%c\n",ln[0],ln[1],search[0],search[1]);
fscanf(fp,"%20[^,],%s[^\n]",ln,name);
printf("1=%c 2=%c 3=%c 4=%c\n",ln[0],ln[1],search[0],search[1]);
```

The 2nd time around the ln[0] gets filled with a lot of spaces or a "\n". I can't tell. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    puts("Enter seach number:");
    char search[2];
    scanf("%c%c",&search[0],&search[1]);

    FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("/Users/user1/Desktop/text.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        puts("File dose not exits");
        return (1);
    }
    else{
        puts("File found");
   }
    char ln[3];
    char name[20];

    fopen("fp","r");
    puts("File opened");

    int searching = 1;

    while(searching == 1)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%20[^,],%s[^\n]",ln,name);

        if(ln[0]==search[0]&&ln[1]==search[1])
        {
            printf("%s",name);
            searching = 0;
        }
        else if(ln[0] == '\n')
        {
            puts("Could not find number");
            searching = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always check return value of *scanf functions. Check the docs to see what it means.

Comment: What is `fopen("fp","r");` for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong use of `fscanf()` format

```
// fscanf(fp,"%20[^,],%s[^\n]",ln,name);
fscanf(fp,"%20[^,],%s%*[^\n]",ln,name);
// or 
fscanf(fp,"%20[^,],%s ",ln,name);
// or 
fscanf(fp," %20[^,],%s",ln,name);
```

Better to check results and add width to `%s`

```
char ln[20+1];
char name[30+1];
if (2 == fscanf(fp,"%20[^,],%30s%*[^\n]",ln,name)) Success();
```

Best to use fgets()

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) == NULL) {
  if (2 == sscanf(buf,"%20[^,],%s",ln,name)) Success();
}
```